# how to clear the failbit while reading the data from input stream?

Tags: c++

I am trying to read the intergers from input stream and as soon it reads the character ( part of input ), failbit is set and it stops reading the stream I want to clear the failbit and read to next input integer.  What changes I should make to get the correct output.

```
int main()
{
    int x;
    while(cin >> x)
    {
       if(cin.fail())
         cin.clear();
       cout << x;
    }
}
```

Input: `12a34`

Expected Output: `1234`

Actual output: `12`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is not checking whether `eofbit` is set before checking `fail`. You need to exit the read loop on `EOF` before testing `fail` and clearing the stream state, e.g.

```
#include <iostream>

int main (void) {

    int x = 0;

    while (1)       /* loop continually reading input */
    {
        if (! (std::cin >> x) ) {   /* check stream state */
            /* if eof() or bad() break read loop */
            if (std::cin.eof() || std::cin.bad())
                break;
            else if (std::cin.fail()) {     /* if failbit */
                std::cin.clear();           /* clear failbit */
                x = std::cin.get();         /* consume next char */
            }
        }
        else        /* on succesful read, just output int */
            std::cout << x;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';  /* tidy up with newline */
}
```

If you check `fail()` first, you will clear `eofbit` and your read will continue.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ echo 12a34 | ./bin/cinint
1234
```

If you want to check `failbit` directly, then use `rdstate()`. In that case you can confirm `failbit` exclusive from `badbit` and then `clear()`, e.g.

```
        if (! (std::cin >> x) ) {       /* check stream state */
            if (std::cin.rdstate() == std::ios_base::failbit) {
                std::cin.clear();       /* if failbit */
                x = std::cin.get();     /* consume next char */
            }
            else    /* else if eofbit or badbit - break read loop */
                break;
        }
        else        /* on succesful read, just output int */
            std::cout << x;
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score -1):

the condition in your while loop will fail when an invalid character is found. You also need to consume the invalid character otherwise the next extraction operation will just fail again:

```
int main()
{
    int x;
    while(true)
    {
       cin >> x;
       if(cin.eof())
       {
           break;
       }
       if(!cin)
       {
           cin.clear();
           //consume the invalid character
           cin.ignore();
           continue;
       }
       cout << x;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Invalid character` such as what?

Comment: @EJP characters which are not integers,, like the 'a' in the OP's question

Answer (score -1):

[Alan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50227617/208273) is almost correct, but you need to put the "if eof" function at the end of the while loop so you can actually read the last value, otherwise it will break break from the file stream early before reading the last value:

```
int main()
{
    int x;
    while(true)
    {
       cin >> x;
       if(!cin)
       {
           cin.clear();
           //consume the invalid character
           cin.ignore();
           continue;
       }
       if(cin.eof())
       {
           break;
       }
       cout << x;
    }
}
```

Comment: The fact that you cannot comment yet is not a reason to abuse answers. Instead you should try to earn the 10 points you need.

Comment: @BoP I assume you mean [the 49 points](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)... Anyway, I've pulled the code from a previous revision of this answer and tweaked it to stand on its own, which should address the concerns raised here.